# emacs undo tree attemp to display deleted buffer?

Tags: emacs

When I call undo-tree-visualize, I get the tree graph just fine.
However, if I try to undo in the visualize buffer, I get `attemp to display deleted buffer` error.

none visualized function works fine. I can undo, redo, switch branch.
But if say I undo once, then call `undo-tree-visualize`, I would get this error: 
`undo-tree-root accessing a non-undo-tree`. I get only get the tree graph when at the latest undo point.

Also, these errors occur in normal file buffer. 
When inside the `*scratch*` buffer, it works without any problem.

I am using the newest version provided in ELPA.

Comment: @wvxvw I am trying to undo in undo-tree-visualize buffer. I find the visualized tree is very helpful to represent which branch I'm on.

Comment: @wvxvw sorry for the confusion. That was what I mean. Though I normally use 'p' 'n' 'f' 'b' for undo/redo, etc

Comment: This works fine for me. You'll need to provide step-by-step instructions explaining how to reproduce the problem, starting from "emacs -Q", before I can help. (You could try using the latest `undo-tree` version from the package web site, since the ELPA version is somewhat outdated. But I doubt your problem has to do with running an older version.)

Comment: @Toby I am getting the same issue, but only for markdown-mode. If I change the mode to text-mode, I am able to see the undo-tree visualization. But after I change back to markdown-mode, I first get `attempt to display detected buffer`. When I revert the buffer and retry getting the undo visualization, I get `undo-tree-root accessing a non-undo-tree`. Can you please check why it is incompatible with markdown-mode? Thanks.

Comment: See above comment. Without a minimal example giving a *complete* and *precise* sequence of steps to reproduce this issue, starting from `emacs -Q`, I cannot help. Also, if you want to report a bug, don't report it on stackexchange! Report it via the proper channels (the appropriate email address is given at the top of the package Commentary).